# Is there a hypernym for persons and companies as entities?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, hypernyms

I have to describe owners of certain properties and those can be persons or companies. I was thinking of naming them *entities*, but that seems too broad.

Comment: What's wrong with _owner_ or _property owner_?

Comment: Both owners and millers refer to the same database with <this word>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Legal entity* - it can be a person, an organization, a corporation, a registered association, a government or any one single entity that can be represented as a single side in court.

Answer (score 1):

In a business context, **party** would be the most suitable term.

Comment: Personally I think that this is the best answer, but it would benefit from linked references to support your claim, say from a dictionary or legal document. Welcome to EL&U Mustapha.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything other than *owner* could better describe this. Other words would be confusing and strange to the readers of your text. I think your misconception comes from the idea that *owner* can only refer to a person or a human being, but that's not the case. For example, you can say that the owner of this property is *Microsoft* or *Apple* and everybody will understand what you mean. Here are some more examples that may help you better understand the usage of *owner*.

> "Microsoft is the owner of Windows 95, Windows 98, Windows NT, Windows 2000 and Visual Basic."
>
> Apple is the owner of iPhone.

And

> Mike is the owner of this website, place, shop, etc.

Comment: Not useful, because more than just owners need to be described.